# GNOME/gdm disable reveal password button

Tags: gnome, login, password, screen-lock, gdm

On the gdm login screen and on the GNOME lockscreen in the password entry box there is this little password reveal button at the right side.

Since this is a toggle some classmates were able to trick me into showing a good portion of my password by just pressing this button while I was away and watching me typing my password in.

Now is there any way to remove this button or show the password only while it is pressed? I've found really NOTHING on this topic on the internet except [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181620/view-password-at-login) askubuntu article asking for exactly the opposite what I want.

Comment: Do you mean that they had access physical access to the mouse *and* could also see your screen while you were typing your password? But to the point: I suggest you try use another [display manager](https://wiki.debian.org/DisplayManager) like `lightdm` instead of `gdm`. `lightdm` sucks too, but a) does not have that feature and b) is a bit more configurable in general.

Comment: And of course, you could use `xdm` too instead of `gdm`.

Comment: @UncleBilly Thank you for the suggestions but this wouldn't solve the problem with the GNOME lockscreen

Comment: Hi, This is possible in recent version of GNOME. May I know the version of gnome-shell/ gnome you are using?

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmNpG.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1IPl.png
  ` $ gdm --version
    GDM 41.0
    $ gnome-shell --version
    GNOME Shell 41.1
    ~]$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the dconf property `disable-show-password` in `/org/gnome/desktop/lockdown` to `true` for the gdm and your own user.

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-show-password true`

Side note: I've stumbled across this prior to asking this question but a bug in GNOME 40 prevented this setting from being recognized. The bug is now resolved and this solution works perfectly well for me now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what OS you are using, but according to Red Hat, this is not possible for RHEL 7. This is because the "show text" functionality is hard-coded into the GDM interface.

Source: [this (short) article](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3224961).

Comment: That article is indeed quite short: "Subscriber exclusive content"

Comment: Can access the article unfortunately. Still believing you though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are interested, you can create a free account and access the article... but it isn't really worth it in this case.